# account linking: The agent returned an empty TTS

Tags: actions-on-google

I define the account linking properties for french. 
It works correctly using french (canada): the response after invoking my app is: " Il semble que votre compte The Keys ne soit pas encore associé. "

But when using french (france), The response in the simulator is: " The agent returned an empty TTS. "

What is the reason of that ?

Comment: In the Overview of your Action in the console, have you set the action to be available to both locales?

Comment: Could you re-create the project supporting french (France) as a new project and retry the account linking? Sometimes, changing the language setting may be failed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't related to the account linking feature.

My server was simply unavailable (`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`).